# foreach com PHP para duas strings

Tags: php

Colegas.

Tenho o seguinte resultado vindo do banco:

> Questões: 1,2,3 Respostas: A,B,C

Gostaria que ficasse da seguinte forma:

> 1 - A; 2 - B; 3 - C;

Tentei usar dois foreach, mas ele está repetindo:

> 1 - A; 1 - B; 2 - A; 2 - B;

Fiz dessa forma:

```
$explodeR = explode(",",$jmTurmas->Respostas;
$explodeQ = explode(",",$jmTurmas->Questoes);

       foreach($explodeQ as $exQ){
                foreach($explodeR as $exR){
                  echo $exQ. " - ".$exR."<br>"; 
                }
            }
```

Comment: Não é mais fácil você usar uma [array associativa](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assim deve dar:

```
$explodeR = explode(",",$jmTurmas->Respostas;
$explodeQ = explode(",",$jmTurmas->Questoes);

foreach($explodeQ as $exQkey => $exQ)
{
    echo $exQ. " - ".$explodeR[$exQkey]."<br>"; 
}
```

Comment: Obrigado lvcs. Funcionou!